# Adding ID to magento filter headers

Tags: php, magento

My client would like individual styles applied to filter headers on the category page in magento.

The headers are pulled in from attributes set up in magento's admin panel, and unfortunately it doesn't assign classes to them, I am trying to put the attribute code in the id.

This is the code that pulls in the filters:

```
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Shop By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
            <div class="actions"><a href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
            <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Options') ?></p>
            <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would like to add the id to the dt in this line:

```
<dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
```

I tried this:

```
<dt id="filter<?php echo $this->__($_filter->getAttributeCode()) ?>"><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
```

But it just outputs nothing where the code should be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, just incase anyone reading wants to know I used:

```
<dt id="filter_<?php echo $_filter->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
```